# Document flow of block level elements when using css :after pseudo selectors

Tags: html, css

- Why does the block level element box '***(red)***' appear after the '***(blue)***' containers content and not after the content box itself?
- How can this be achieved using css `:after` selector?

---

## TEST AREA

[image]

**CSS**

```
div{
    background:#59c;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
div:after{
    background:#b55;
    content: "I SHOULD BE AFTER CONTENT BOX";
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: the :after pseudo element is appended as the last child of the selector element.. you can see it in browser dev tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning for the pseudo element :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hd548ypw/1/)**

```
div:after{
    position:absolute; /* <-- add this */
    top:100%; /* <-- and this */
    background:#b55;
    content: "I SHOULD BE AFTER CONTENT BOX";
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Nice I never realised until now top 100% will be inline with baseline. But why does the element not align after the content box as default?

Comment: The ::after pseudo element is inserted after the content on the element you apply it, not the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

This will work as you expect :

```
div {
    background:#59c;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
div:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #b55;
    content: "I SHOULD BE AFTER CONTENT BOX";
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```